# Rename Multiple dataframes based on file names in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am running a loop where I am reading all the docx files in a folder in multiple dataframes.
I need to save each document into different dataframes and name each dataframes as same as the name of the files.
Note: I am refraining to  store the dataframes in a dictionary with the filenames as keys.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
     for document in files:
         if document.endswith('.docx'):
             table_num=4
             nheader=2
             joined_path = os.path.join(directory,document)
             document1 = Document(joined_path)
             table =document1.tables[table_num-1]
             data=[[cell.text for cell in row.cells] for row in table.rows]
             df = pd.DataFrame(data)
             outside_col,inside_col =df.iloc[0],df.iloc[1]
             hier_index =pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(outside_col,inside_col)))
             df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=hier_index).drop(df.index[[0,1]]).reset_index(drop=True)
             df['company'] = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(document))
             df+_+str(os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(document))) = df # tried here and getting error
```

Comment: Easiest way would be to store the dataframes in a dictionary with the filenames as keys.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen yes but I am refraining from do that currently.

Comment: Then you'll have to work with with variable variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables